# Does my jQuery Image preloader function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, lightbox, preloader

I've written a function which will load all large images from a lightbox gallery which are referenced by a link ( for those who don't know) after all small images are loaded $(window).load().

Here's the code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if ($('ul#gallery').length > 0) {
        // make a container, fill in images and attach it to the page body
        var c = $("<div />").attr({style: 'display: none', id: 'gallerypreload'});
        $("ul#gallery li > a").each(function() {
            $('<img />').attr('src', $(this).attr('href')).appendTo(c);
        });
        c.appendTo('body');
    }
});
```

The gallery looks like this:

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li><a href="/img/image.jpg" title="Image title"><img src="img/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image title" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="/img/image.jpg" title="Image title"><img src="img/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image title" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="/img/image.jpg" title="Image title"><img src="img/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image title" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="/img/image.jpg" title="Image title"><img src="img/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image title" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="/img/image.jpg" title="Image title"><img src="img/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Image title" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to do this, because the browser is supposed to load all thumbnails first and THEN preload larger images for viewing. Also, I've written some sort of fading effect which is triggered by $(window).load(), too.

My Question here is: Do ALL browsers preload images attached to the body in a  container? Hence it is not displayed, theoretically they shouldn't load the images, or do they? Should I style `visibility: hidden; width:0; height:0` or is my approach working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can force the preload by creating javascript image objects with the src you want to preload

```
$("ul#gallery li > a").each(function() {
    var preload = new Image();
    preload.src = $(this).attr('href');
    $('<img />').attr('src', preload.src).appendTo(c);
});
```

Then it shouldn't matter if the IMG tags are visible or not

---

Based on the comments below, this should be enough to preload the images:

```
$("ul#gallery li > a").each(function() {
    var preload = new Image();
    preload.src = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

or even

```
$("ul#gallery li > a").each(function() {
   (new Image()).src = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: @Vincent: Yes, using Image objects to preload stuff is the oldest method around. I've been using it since the last millenium :)

Comment: OK thanks man. But do I need to append image tags to the dom then? Can the image object stand alone ? I'm now using `new Image().src = $(this).attr('href');`. Thanks.

Comment: @Vincent: Yes, you still need to append actual IMG tags to the document if you want the images shown. The JS Image object only exists "in code"; it's not an html tag, it's just data.

Comment: No, I don't want the images shown. The appended <img>-Tags are in a <div style="display: none"></div>-Tag. The actual image is shown by Slimbox2, a leightweight Lightbox clone. So then I don't need these anymore? Thanks.

Comment: @Vincent: You may need to add some parentheses to your code, i.e. `(new Image()).src = ....` and it should work. But really, it's just as easy to keep on two lines for clarity.

Comment: @Vincent: Ah, ok, if you already have something that'll show the images, then no, you don't need to add them to the document yourself. You can just do the Image-object stuff and skip the rest